# Electron app with protractor end-to-end testing

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, electron

I'm currently working on an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app and I now want to integrate end-to-end testing with [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/). I've reviewed the tutorials for Protractor and am now trying to adapt it to Electron. Since Electron runs as a standalone app, how do I do this?

It seems that Protractor stands-up a Selenium server that then tries to reach out to an available HTTP server and run tests such as click here, what url am I on, input this text, etc.

Therefore how would I go about allowing the selenium server access to the electron instance?

Anyway that's my mindset on the situation, any help is appreciated and feel free to correct any of my assumptions.

Comment: Have you seen how to use Selemium with Electron: https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver.md ? Don't know about Protractor though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapting the instructions documented at [Using Selenium and WebDriver](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver.md), here is what you need to put into your protractor config (using [`directConnect`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/docs/server-setup.md#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers), as an example):

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,

    capabilities: {
         browserName: "chrome",
         chromeOptions: {
             binary: '/Path-to-Your-App.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom'  // < IMPORTANT! 
         },  
    },

    // ...
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: Cool so I tried the `directConnect` and that worked. My real issue though was that I needed to actually build my app then point to that as the binary. Therefore if you can tweak your answer to put emphasis on the binary (is your built app) then i'll accept this answer.

Comment: @cha55son yeah, `binary` is the key thing to configure. `directConnect` was just for the sake of an example and simplicity .

Comment: @alecxe this is great! The only issue is that the `binary` key needs to be under `chromeOptions` see @BladeBarringer's answer for a correction.

Answer (score 4):

alecxe's answer is mostly correct, but there's one slight inaccuracy with it.

binary should be nested under chromeOptions like so:

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  capabilities: {
     browserName: "chrome",
     chromeOptions: {
       binary: '/Path-to-Your-App.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom'  // < IMPORTANT!
     }
   },

  // ...
}
```