# Electron: Run end to end tests with protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, electron

We are making a desktop app with Electron using AngularJS, we want to make end-to-end tests using Protractor, the problem is that we got issues on running it, we don't really know what is the problem but looks like there is some synchronization problems, like it's not waiting for the page to load, not closing the app after the test is finished.

Here is the protractor configuration file:

```
 const ELECTRON_PATH = '/usr/bin/electron';
const APP_PATH = '/home/me/project/myapp';

exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    framework: 'mocha',
    specs: [
        'test.js'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        platform: 'LINUX',
        chromeOptions: {
            binary: ELECTRON_PATH,
            args: ['app=' + APP_PATH, '--e2e-testing']
        }
    },
    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.resetUrl = 'file://';
    }
};
```

Comment: Protractor isn't for desktop testing.  It's for websites.

Comment: I know, but Electron allow us to run web apps on desktop, it simply embeds Chrome in a desktop window, I just managed to run protractor with it like I said, but the problem that I'm not sure if my configuration is correct

Comment: Check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329361/electron-app-with-protractor-end-to-end-testing#answer-31341341) and see if that helps. They suggest the binary key should be the path to your built app, not the electron binary.

Comment: @TehBeardedOne Thank you, but it's the same thing, what I actually did is providing the electron binary with my app path as an argument, it did the same issue.